# How do you create a course in a REST API using mysql and mux?

Tags: mysql, rest, go, mux

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Course struct {
ID    string `json:"ID"`
    Title string `json:"Title"`
}

var db *sql.DB

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the REST API!")
}


func createCourse(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r)

    results, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO Courses VALUES (?)(?)") //course id and title
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    reqBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    keyVal := make(map[string]string)
    json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &keyVal)
    title := keyVal["title"]
    _, err = results.Exec(params["id"], title)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "New post was created")
}

func main() {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:61876)/my_db")

    // handle error
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Database opened")
    }
    defer db.Close()
    // instantiate courses

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/", home)
    //router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/courses/{id}", createCourse).Methods("POST")

    fmt.Println("Listening at port 5000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router)
}
```

I want to create a course using the method POST but I am not sure how to continue on. Right now I am using Mux and docker to my sql which I have succeeded in running. I know there is way where i create a map and do a `json.Unmarshal(reqbody,&map)`and do a `sql.Stmt.Exec` of the key value `title`. Is there a way to do it using `params := mux.Vars(r)`?

Added comments:I have edited the createCourse function to include params and the struct to include ID. However,my createCourse function is not working as intended and I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

To create a course, use POST method http request, because in REST apis, POST method using for create entities. Send your course title in request body as a json (or form) and create ID inside your service. you can get incremental ID from Sql Database. And send that ID in response, then Frontend can use that id for future updates of the course.

Use json request body like below,

```
{
   "title": "mytitle"
}
```

and unmarshal it to Struct type below.

```
type CreateCourseRequest struct {
    Title string `json:"title"`
}
```

You can unmarshal request in your `createCourse` function like this

```
    reqBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    course := CreateCourseRequest{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &course)
    if err != nil {
        //handle error here
    }
    title := course.title
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have edited my CreateCourse function to include params and the struct to include ID. However,my createCourse function is not working as intended and I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: `/api/v1/courses/{id}` in this path, you can get `params["id"]`
if `api/vi/courses/123` is your path, then `params["id"] = 123`, but you are not getting a `title` from param because you are not getting it from your path. can you explain your real url path, and hi light `id` and title`?

Comment: Previously I was using a Course `struct` with only `title string` and so I use params["course_title"] instead. But I decided to change the sql table where the `Course table` has `id` and `title`. so now I am using ` router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/courses/{id}", createCourse).Methods("POST")` instead and the `params["id"]` I use this instead of `params["title"]`

Comment: I have edited the answer,  Ask anything if you have any concern about it